# How to get path of multiple selected images from gallery

Tags: java, android, path

How to get the real path of multiple selected pictures from gallery stocked in  an array? I was searching and I just found how to get the real path of one picture:

```
public static String getFileNameByUri(Context context, Uri uri)
  {
      String fileName="unknown";//default fileName
      Uri filePathUri = uri;
      if (uri.getScheme().toString().compareTo("content")==0)
      {
          Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
          if (cursor.moveToFirst())
          {
              int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);//Instead of "MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA" can be used "_data"
              filePathUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(column_index));
              fileName = filePathUri.getLastPathSegment().toString();
          }
      }
      else if (uri.getScheme().compareTo("file")==0)
      {
          fileName = filePathUri.getLastPathSegment().toString();
      }
      else
      {
          fileName = fileName+"_"+filePathUri.getLastPathSegment();
      }
      return fileName;
  }
```

Comment: So, how did you solf this issue? When you have selected only one image the solution is: String filePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(getActivity(), intent.getData()); What about if you have selected multiple images?